# PyCharm Not Properly Recognizing Requirements - Python, Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Often requirements show up in `requirements.txt` like this:

`django-registration`

But in `INSTALLED_APPS` it appears as `registration`. So when you import like:

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
```

This is valid but PyCharm is showing a red squiggly line under the word **registration** in `from registration...` that says "Package 'registration' is not listed in project requirements".

How can I remedy this?

**UPDATE**

I was able to find a way to make the warning go away but it's not a good solution. If you simply add the package name to the `requirements.txt` file the warning goes away, but then that requirement is not valid if you were to install with `pip`. For example, I'm also using `pygooglevoice` which is how it's written in `requirements.txt` but when it's imported in the code, you write:

```
from googlevoice import Voice
```

This seems weird because I use PyCharm for many projects and I'm just noticing this with a recent project I'm working on...

Comment: Then just click `ignore this requirement`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I know what you are talking about... But the message and option you are thinking of appears if there is a requirement in your code that is not in your requirements file. My situation is that the requirement is named something different in the requirements file compared to the `INSTALLED_APPS` configuration. PyCharm is confused because it thinks the requirement should be called `django-registration` but it's in the import statement as `registration`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After seeing this phenomenon again, I did some more digging. After setting certain folders as source roots and restarting PyCharm, these reference warnings went away. I think this is a bug in PyCharm.

Comment: This is likely addressedin the new version: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/

Comment: I recently encountered this same issue in the newest PyCharm version (4.5.4) as of September 11, '15. After setting my django root directory (not the root of my project) as a Source folder, it seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue with django-watson in PyCharm 2016.1.

Comment: I already had my source root folder set correctly and I encountered this issue on version 2017.2.3 of PyCharm. Restarting the IDE resolved it.

Comment: Also note that using multiple Content Roots can confuse the plugin since PyCharm use alphabetical order for Content Roots.  I had to rename the project for my library to zz-libname to fix my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with `apache-airflow` package

Answer (score 22):

JetBrains claims that this is fixed in version 2017.2:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11963#comment=27-2248728

I can confirm this (in IntelliJ IDEA). Also, it's worth double-checking that the correct requirements file is specified in `Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools -> Package requirements file`

Comment: This is still an issue in 2020.

Comment: And also in 2022.

Comment: it's 2023 and I'm here to find the solution!

Comment: This works in my PyCharm 2019.3 (I am using Windows 7). By default, PyCharm sets the default requirements file as Python.exe, which is wrong. The trick is routing the requirement as @iver56 recommends, to requirements.txt file.

Answer (score 16):

This seem to be an open issue

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11963

Comment: Status "fixed". Erroneously in my opinion. New issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23335

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm should be able to figure this out, but it doesn't. For now, I just add # noinspection PyPackageRequirements to each import with this warning to suppress it. I'd rather not, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed using the following commands in the terminal (using linux, not sure if this will work on windows, but I see no reason why it shouldn't, I haven't tried on windows.)

**If you haven't created a requirements.txt file already**

```
touch requirements.txt
```

**This should do the trick**

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install flask
```

*For better understanding, I recommend reading this*

https://boscacci.medium.com/why-and-how-to-make-a-requirements-txt-f329c685181e

Comment: This is more the prerequisite for the problem and not a solution. If you wouldn't have a requirement.txt you wouldn't get the problem.

Comment: have you tried to use in your example django-registration ?