# Python requirements.txt aliases to quiet IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py, requirements.txt

Some requirements have different `pip` names than they do when you import them.  For example, Discord.py is installed by using `pip install discord.py`, but when you use it in code, it's just `import discord`.

Therefore PyCharm complains that "package not listed in requirements.txt".

How can I quiet this error, or alias the package in requirements.txt so it recognizes that it uses different names?

Comment: You may have to write `https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py` in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: If all you want to do is make PyCharm quiet, you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817903/4110924